# Python_code все работает просто не понимаю одну вещь

Tags: python, функции, циклы

(я только начал изучать этот язык так что многое не понимаю)
по логике `Tab` перед `return person` не нужен но без него ошибка происходит, а и да функция должна добавлять в словарь новие елементы (от 3) создавая для них новые ключи
Не знаю почему так если кто-то имеет много свободного времени объясните пожалуйсто:)

```
def make_album(name,alb_name,age = None,*songs):

    x = len(songs)
    print(x)
    person = {'name' : name , "name of album" : alb_name }
    if age:
        person['age'] = age
    for i in range(x) :
        for song in songs:
            person[f"{'songs'}{i+1}"] = song
            i = i+1
        return person

album = make_album("Tom Odell","another love",23,"tgr","asd","sdfg","fgj0",)
print(album)
```

Comment: Попробуй чётче сформулировать свои мысли и постараться в грамматику. Тяжело читать такой текст.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(x) :
```

Фактически этот цикл у вас используется только для того, чтобы инициализировать переменную `i` нулём, а больше он ни для чего не нужен, переменную `i` вы и так внутри вложенного цикла вручную перебираете `i = i+1`, и `songs` внутренним же циклом перебираете. Поэтому `return` так странно и стоит, что выйти из функции нужно уже после первой итерации этого бесполезного цикла по `i`.
Более оптимальный код цикла (только одного, два вложенных цикла не нужны) должен выглядеть так:

```
for i,song in enumerate(songs):
    person[f"{'songs'}{i+1}"] = song
return person
```